# Looking for a short story where a girl's body is described as a galaxy

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

It's a very short short story, and for almost the whole story it's describing a girl's body as a galaxy, and then at the end it says something like "and he was an astronaut."

Comment: Any science fiction elements at all?

Comment: Not off-topic, but can you please edit the title to be a bit more descriptive and 'searchable'?

Comment: @user14111 True. Fixed it! You know, you have enough rep to fix it as well ;)

Comment: @AndresF. I know, but I usually let the OP have a chance to do it (because they know what they are searching for), and then if they don't then I jump-in and surmise a title for them :)

Comment: Not SciFi.................................

Comment: Without more description, this does look off-topic.  You can describe someone in astronomical terms without there being any sci-fi elements in the story at all.  VTC.  If the OP can provide some story elements that make it clear it's sci-fi will be glad to revoke or vote to reopen.

Comment: [Meta discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4996/10622).

Answer (score 21):

Could this be "**[She Was a Galaxy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:4jJJzDSwzicJ:www.hoosicvalley.k12.ny.us/hs/docs11-12/2012-CreativeWriting-Spring.pdf%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk)**" by Nicole Carknard?

> She was a galaxy
>
> Her eyes held the moon
>
> Her spirit the sun
>
> Her heart shone like a supernova
>
> Her mind held the deep complexity of the constellations
>
> She was a mystery
>
> He was an astronaut
>
> Space bound.